# search list for existing entries

Tags: python, pyqt5

for user input , if the user enters a duplicate entry

it must throw out an error , if it is blank , no entry must be submitted

i feel like ive missed something

```
def add(self):
    row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Country Dialog", "Enter country")

    try:
        if ok and text is not None:
            self.listWidget.insertItem(row, text)

    except:
        if text and ok in self.listWidget.currentRow():
            self.QMessageBox("list item already exists")
```

Comment: When you use `try`, the `except` part is only entered when the code produces a "real" error. I think you're better off here with `if ok ...: ... else: ...` without `try`?

Comment: ive adjusted it according to the answer given below, and tried his answer with still no luck , ive also tried to reshape it into. still fails

     `def add(self):
        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Country Dialog", "Enter country")
        texts = [item.text() for item in self.listWidget.Items()]

        if text in texts():
            self.QMessageBox("list item already exists")
        if text is not None:
            self.listWidget.insertItem(row, text`

Answer (score 0):

`currentRow()` does not hold the rows. It only has the selected row.
Moreover, you check if `ok` is in `currentRow()`. I think this is a typo.
You need to check every rows with loop in `self.listWidget.items()`.

```
def add(self):
    # not the best way but at least, it works
    texts = [item.text() for item in self.listWidget.items()]

    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Country Dialog", "Enter country")

    if ok:
        if text:
            if text in texts:
                self.QMessageBox("list item already exists")
            else:
                self.listWidget.insertItem(row, text)
        else:
            self.QMessageBox("text is empty")
```

Comment: for some reason this breaks my button for add , and just causes it to crash? :/